# GRUB2 Parameters, how to edit them

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu Server 11.10 boot, white terminal with garbled black text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98294/ubuntu-server-11-10-boot-white-terminal-with-garbled-black-text)

I need to add a parameter to the grub entry for ubuntu.

console=ttyl

how do i set this? I know how to do it manually for each boot but how do i set it to be automatically passed as a param?

I am using GRUB 2 and Ubuntu 11.10

Thanks,
Speed

Comment: I answered in your other question http://askubuntu.com/questions/98294/solvedubuntu-server-11-10-boot-white-terminal-with-garbled-black-text , sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

If you want this parameter to be permanently added to your default linux boot parameters you should modify the GRUB configuration file.
Edit your “/etc/default/grub” and modify the appropriate line to be something like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash console=ttyl"`.
Save the file and run `update-grub` so that changes will take affect.

Comment: That screwed my boot up. Itplaced the param in a line begining with linux\ ....... and would not boot.